# Creating a list from a excel file

Tags: pandas, excel

fairly new to the world, i need to create a code witch will create a list with information  from row A and H from a excel file witch contain an specific error code from row F, and than croscheck the information from row H with row B and filter those to only those once containing a number >20 in row M and import those back into a new sheet in a new excel file.

Came this far and have problems continuing further

import pandas as pd

excel_file_path = ('C:\Users\MarkoHrupacki\Downloads\Read DB Calls_2024_01_30.xlsm')

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

filtered_df = df[df['F'] == '00000843']

result_list = filtered_df['H'].tolist()

print(result_list)

Comment: please provide a [mre] of the data, but basically you need to use the same logic `df[df['your_col'] > 20]`. If not, be explicit and give concrete examples.